# Issue with generating self-sign certificate with proper SAN field

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to configure Janus Gateway and I am experiencing with an issue with my self-signed certificate, see log below

`Jan 25 09:50:46 localhost platform: [2018/01/25 09:50:46 EST] [EROR] /api/v4/webrtc/token:WebRTC.Token code=500 rid=7mgqedeejpnt3gginnpj5ikape uid=k7m4t6r663frfqaoo5enspfuqh ip=192.168.20.3 We encountered an error while connecting to the server [details: Post https://192.168.20.140:7889/admin: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.20.140 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs]`

My hostname is webrtc, IP address is 192.168.20.140 and local DNS is 192.168.20.1

My understanding is I probably didnd't have the SAN information in my certificate so I modified the command that generates the certificate request by following online tutorials.  See my configuration file below.

```
[ req ]
default_bits            = 2048                  # RSA key size
encrypt_key             = yes                   # Protect private key
default_md              = sha256                # MD to use
utf8                    = yes                   # Input is UTF-8
string_mask             = utf8only              # Emit UTF-8 strings
prompt                  = yes                   # Prompt for DN
distinguished_name      = san_dn           # DN template
x509_extensions     = v3_ca
req_extensions          = san_reqext       # Desired extensions
x509_extensions     = usr_cert

[ san_dn ]
countryName             = "1. Country Name (2 letters) (eg, US)       "
countryName_max         = 2
stateOrProvinceName     = "2. State or Province Name   (eg, region)   "
localityName            = "3. Locality Name            (eg, city)     "
organizationName        = "4. Organization Name        (eg, company)  "
organizationalUnitName  = "5. Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)  "
commonName              = "6. Common Name              (eg, full name)"
commonName_max          = 64

[ san_reqext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
basicConstraints    = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage        = critical,codeSigning, msCodeInd, msCodeCom
nsCertType      = client,server,email,objsign
subjectAltName      = @alt_names

[ usr_cert ]
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
basicConstraints    = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage        = critical,codeSigning, msCodeInd, msCodeCom
nsCertType      = client,server,email,objsign
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer

[ alt_names ]
DNS.0           = localhost
DNS.1           = webrtc
DNS.2           = 192.168.20.140
DNS.3           = 192.168.20.1
```

Below is the command I use to generate my certificate request

```
openssl req -new -key ./webrtc_secret.key -config ./san_request.cfg -out ./webrtc.csr
```

Below is the command I use to generate the certificate using my self-sign CA and generated certificate request

```
openssl x509 -req -in ./webrtc.csr -CA ./rootCA.pem -CAkey ./rootCA.key -CAcreateserial \
-out ./webrtc.pem -days 365 -sha256
```

Can you spot anything wrong with my certificate request?

Update 1:

Looks like my generated certificate request has the right information.

```
Requested Extensions:
    X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
        F0:CA:B8:FE:FA:CE:29:CE:0E:CB:01:93:B6:97:96:30:8E:B3:16:DB
    X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
        CA:FALSE
    X509v3 Key Usage: critical
        Digital Signature
    X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
        Code Signing, Microsoft Individual Code Signing, Microsoft Commercial Code Signing
    Netscape Cert Type: 
        SSL Client, SSL Server, S/MIME, Object Signing
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
        DNS:localhost, DNS:webrtc, DNS:192.168.20.140, DNS:192.168.20.1
```

Update 2
So you would think openssl would use all your information from the certificate request when generating the certificate.  WRONG!  I have to manually specify the extension when generating the self-sign certificate using certificate request.  See below example below...  This might be the answer.  I am going to try it now

```
openssl x509 -req -in ./webrtc.csr -CA ./rootCA.pem -CAkey ./rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out ./webrtc.pem -days 365 -sha256 -extfile ./san_ext.cfg -extensions san_reqext

[ req ]
req_extensions          = san_reqext       # Desired extensions

[ san_reqext ]
subjectAltName      = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.0           = localhost
DNS.1           = mattermost
IP.0            = 192.168.20.140
IP.1            = 192.168.20.1
```

Not sure where is the lost of information.

Comment: Are you sure the service is using the right certificate file? Have you restarted it since you updated the cert?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's taking my certificate because I would get different error message when I insert another certificate.  For example, if I didn't have the chained certificate then I would get an unknown ca error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read my whole question and then read my update 2.  Update 2 has the answer in detail.

So you would think openssl would use all your information from the certificate request when generating the certificate. WRONG! I have to manually specify the extension when generating the self-sign certificate using certificate request.

Here's an example...

```
openssl x509 -req -in ./webrtc.csr -CA ./rootCA.pem -CAkey ./rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out ./webrtc.pem -days 365 -sha256 -extfile ./san_ext.cfg -extensions san_reqext

[ req ]
req_extensions          = san_reqext       # Desired extensions

[ san_reqext ]
subjectAltName      = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.0           = localhost
DNS.1           = mattermost
IP.0            = 192.168.20.140
IP.1            = 192.168.20.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The IP addresses in the Subject Alternate Name section need to be identified as `IP`, instead of `DNS`. So change the `alt_names` section of your OpenSSL configuration file to look like this:

```
[ alt_names ]
DNS.0           = localhost
DNS.1           = webrtc
IP.0            = 192.168.20.140
IP.1            = 192.168.20.1
```

Then regenerate the request and certificate.

Comment: The request does include SAN but the generated certificate still doesn't have the SAN.

`X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:localhost, DNS:mattermost, IP Address:192.168.20.140, IP Address:192.168.20.1
`

I try to print the certificate using the following command and DNS information shows up.

`openssl x509 -text -noout -in target/webrtc.pem | grep DNS`

Comment: Try adding `-extensions usr_cert` to the `openssl x509` command that you use to sign the cert. According to the manual page for x509, extensions from the request aren't included unless you ask for them.